# How to compute prime twins between two bounds?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to compute the first 20 primes that have a 2 number gap between them - E.G 3 and 5.

```
divides :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool 
divides x y = y `mod` x == 0

prime :: Integer -> Bool
prime n = n > 1 && and [not(divides x n) | x <- [2..(n-1)]]

allprimes :: [Integer]
allprimes = [x | x<- [2..], prime x]

primeTest3 :: Integer -> [Integer] 
primeTest3 n = [ if y - x == 2 then y  else x | x <- [3..n], y <- [2..n],  prime x]
```

This works to a certain point, the if `n = 20`, then the output is `3, 5, ,5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9..` Etc. This is obviously due to the if else statement. How can I get it to print out how many twin primes there are between a certain number without duplicates?

Comment: also, take a look at [`zip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:zip) - you can do: `areTwoApart (x,y) = x - y == 2` and something like `filter areTwoApart (zip allprimes (tail allprimes))` to get a bit closer to what you want.

Comment: Sorry, in my last comment it should be `y - x` not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

To organize what I wrote in the comment:

```
areTwoApart (x,y) = y - x == 2
filter areTwoApart (zip allprimes (tail allprimes))
```

...will give you the list of prime pairs, without duplicates:

```
Prelude> take 10 $ filter areTwoApart (zip allprimes (tail allprimes))
[(3,5),(5,7),(11,13),(17,19),(29,31),(41,43),(59,61),(71,73),(101,103),(107,109)]
```

As for your final question "how many twin primes there are between a certain number without duplicates", I'm not sure what you mean by "between". But you can probably use the function above to get to it.